# How to Foward Declare Classes Across Files C++

Tags: c++, class

I have been trying to figure out how to forward declare classes across multiple files in C++. I was able to successfully do it with two classes, but doing this across many classes puzzled me. I tried forward declaring all the classes in a header file and including that in all the classes, but I got the error of incomplete classes. I looked into it, but all the solutions seemed unreasonable or confused me. Can you please explain a good way to do it.

If it helps here is some example code of the issue that specifically occurring. Class A is included in Class C, but Class A also includes Class B which holds Class C resulting in an error because Class C has not been declared.

Class Forward Declaration

```
//Tried "Class Name {};" but that also failed
Class A;
Class B;
Class C;
```

Class A

```
//Class A
#include "B.h"

class A{
 private:
  B b;
 public:
  void SetBInt(int set) {b.SetInt(set);}
}
```

Class B

```
//Class B
#include "C.h"
class B{
 private:
  C c;
  int i = 0;
 public:
  void SetInt(int set){i = set;}
}
```

Class C

```
//Class C
#include "A.h"
class C{
 private:
  int i = 0;
 public:
  void SetInt(int set){i = set;}
}
```

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency that appears to be unnecessary. Why does `C.h` need to include `A.h`?

Comment: *"Class A is included in Class C"* - This doesn't match the example you've given.

Comment: Note that forward declaring only helps for pointer and reference types.  If your class holds a non-pointer/reference to another type, forward declaring won't solve your problem, because the compiler must know the size of the type to determine the memory layout for the class.

Comment: Cyclic dependencies are tricky, and the details matter a lot. Please make your posted code reflect your actual code otherwise we're all wasting our time.

Comment: The relationship A includes B, B includes C, C includes A is not doable, unless you use pointers or references.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Class A for me is like the main class that holds many variables that need to be given to the other classes so it is essential to include it. Class B is like an object class and I need the main class to be able to understand the object class so add objects and alter them from the main class. Currently class C is a texture class so I need to include it in class B, but class C also needs a variable from class A so I have to include that too which results in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to avoid circular dependencies.  One common way to avoid them is by pre-declaring the type, and not having any instances or function calls of that type in the header.

You do this by changing instances, such as `B b`, into references or pointers: `B* b`.  You also have to move any code that uses `b` into the CPP file, so you can `#include "B.h"` prior to using it.

For example, instead of

```
// we'll remove this header's dependency on B shortly
#include "B.h"

class A
{
  B b;
public:
  A() { b.SetInt(0); }
};
```

You do something like this:

```
class B;

class A
{
  B *b; // *pointers and &references to a predeclared class are fine.
public:
  A();
  ~A();
};
```

... and then in A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h" // ALWAYS include your own header first
#include "B.h"

A::A()
{
  // we didn't need to know how big B was until now, when we're about to make one and
  // run its constructor.  We'll also need to know what functions are available, and the
  // types of all its parameters (or lack of parameters).
  b = new B();
  b->SetInt(0);
}

A::~A()
{
  delete b; // for every "new" there must be a "delete"
}
```

Yes, this would be (much) better with `std::unique_ptr<B> b` instead of a raw pointer.  With a smart pointer we wouldn't need an explicit destructor.  I just didn't want to throw too much potentially new stuff at someone still learning.

Alternatively, you could pass a reference into the constructor, and use the member initializer list (you can only set references when they're constructed).  This raises problems with "Object Lifetime".  If the instance of B you pass in at construction time is destructed before A is done with it, you're program will violently crash (if you're lucky: that way you'll have a good idea of what the problem is) the next time it's used.  Best to avoid it till you have considerably more experience under your belt.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so far it has fixed the issue!